# using multiple dynamic jquery

Tags: jquery

im trying to use the following code

`$('#monbus1').change(function() {
    $('#montype1').toggle();
});`

to edit a set of dynamic divs, i was wondering do i have to make one of these for each div i want to show or is there a way to do it all auto so i dont have to have 15 of those (i allow up to 15 boxes to be made with

```
$("#monaddButton").click(function () {
if(moncounter>15){
        alert("Only 15 textboxes allowed,if more needed let me know");
        return false;
}   

var MonNewTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'Mondiv' + moncounter);

MonNewTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div><label>Arrival time:</label><input type="time" id="monarr' + moncounter + '" name="monarr' + moncounter + '"></div><div><label>Place/Location:</label><input type="text" id="monadd' + moncounter +
'" name="monadd' + moncounter + '"></div><div><label>Work/Activities:</label><input type="textbox" id="monadd' + moncounter + '" name="monadd' + moncounter +
'"></div><div><label>Departure time:</label><input type="time" id="mondep' + moncounter + '" name="mondep' + moncounter + '"></div><label>Bus</label><input type="checkbox" id="monbus' + moncounter +
'" name="monbus' + moncounter + '"><label>Walking</label><input type="checkbox" id="monwal' + moncounter + '" name="monwal' + moncounter + '"><label>Other</label><input type="checkbox" id="monoth' + moncounter +
'" name="monoth' + moncounter + '"><div id="nummonbus' + moncounter + '" style="display:none">Bus #:<input type="text" id="busmon' + moncounter + '" name="busmon' + moncounter + '" size="4"></div><div id="nummonoth' + moncounter +
'" style="display:none">Other:<input type="text" name="othmon' + moncounter + '" id="othmon' + moncounter + '"></div>');

MonNewTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#Mondaydiv");`
```

i have been trying to work it out, but im still learning how to use dynamic content, i fixed some of the other small bugs i was having but could not figure this one out, thank you in advanced for your help

Comment: please don't build html with strings in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation -

```
$('#Mondaydiv').on('change','#monbus1',function() {
   $('#montype1').toggle();
});
```

To bind `change` event on all of your `monbus` input -

```
$('#Mondaydiv').on('change','[id^=monbus]',function() {
       var count = this.id.replace('monbus','');
       $('#montype'+count).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is select all of the divs that you are interested in, and apply the change function to all of them.

If the div with id Mondaydiv contains all of the child divs that you want to apply that function to, you can use the `.each` function on the children of that div to add this change function:

```
$('#Mondaydiv').children().each(function() { 

    $(this).change(function() { 
           $(this).toggle(); 
    });

);
```

This assumes that the only children of `#Mondaydiv` are the `monbus*` divs that you want to apply this to. If that isn't the case, you'll need to select them in another way, such as by giving them all a unique class and using the `find` function with that class as the selector on '#Mondaydiv'.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to parse exactly what you want to have happen, but I would suggest that you use CSS classes rather than IDs to target the elements in question, and add a mapping between the elements.

For instance, add a class of `monbus` to all of the `input`s you currently have an ID with a prefix of `monbus` on. Also add a `data-` attribute to indicate the corresponding element. So, instead of:

```
'<input type="checkbox" id="monbus' + moncounter + '" name="monbus' + moncounter + '">'
```

use:

```
'<input class="monbus" data-toggle="montype' + moncounter + '" type="checkbox" id="monbus' + moncounter + '" name="monbus' + moncounter + '">'
```

Then your code becomes simply:

```
$('.monbus').change(function() { 
    var whatToToggle = $(this).data('toggle'); 
    $('#' + whatToToggle).toggle(); 
});
```